# Almost no sound [ALC294] in Vivobook Pro 15 - Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: sound, 22.04, pulseaudio, alsa, intel

This might be a popular type of question, but since none of the workarounds related to this worked for me, I just have to ask.

I have **ASUS Vivobook Pro 15 K6500ZC-HN364 (i7-12650H)**. I've just (re)installed Ubuntu 22.04 (almost fresh - installed updates, NVidia proprietary graphics driver, and `alsa-tools`).

In the sound settings I can see that system recognizes the output device as *Speakers - Built-in Audio*, and if I plug in mini-jack headphones, it recognizes 'em too as *Headphones - Built-in Audio*

If I play audio or test it in settings while headphones are not plugged in, I can hear no sound. With the headphones, I hear a kind of bit-crushed ear-bleeding sound.

In both situations, however, the sound level visualizer (that one in the settings under the Output Device dropdown) reacts to the sound, it acts like everything is OK. But it's not, obviously

I've tried every available workaround related to sound problems on Ubuntu, even this one with an executable bash file and reboot:

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo hda-verb /dev/snd/hwC0D0 0x20 0x500 0x1b

sudo hda-verb /dev/snd/hwC0D0 0x20 0x477 0x4a4b

sudo hda-verb /dev/snd/hwC0D0 0x20 0x500 0xf

sudo hda-verb /dev/snd/hwC0D0 0x20 0x477 0x74
```

but unfortunately, nothing fixes the problem.

Another thing is that immediately after startup I have *Dummy Output* in Output Device but in a few seconds everything here goes back to normal (I guess it's OK due to sound servers loading).

---

Here is some technical information (I'll add more if needed):

```bash
ASUSLaptop-K6500ZC-K6500ZC:~$ inxi -xxz --audio
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel Alder Lake PCH-P High Definition Audio vendor: ASUSTeK
    driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus-ID: 0000:00:1f.3 chip-ID: 8086:51c8
  Device-2: NVIDIA vendor: ASUSTeK driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel
    bus-ID: 0000:01:00.1 chip-ID: 10de:2291
  Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k5.15.0-58-generic running: yes
  Sound Server-2: PulseAudio v: 15.99.1 running: yes
  Sound Server-3: PipeWire v: 0.3.48 running: yes
```

```bash
ASUSLaptop-K6500ZC-K6500ZC:~$ cat /proc/asound/cards
 0 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
                      HDA Intel PCH at 0x612f288000 irq 189
 1 [NVidia         ]: HDA-Intel - HDA NVidia
                      HDA NVidia at 0x86080000 irq 17
```

```bash
Vivobook-ASUSLaptop-K6500ZC-K6500ZC:~$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC294 Analog [ALC294 Analog]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Is this related to [this bug](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=206589)? And are there any more workarounds for this problem?

I mean, if there are no solutions and the only way is to wait until some patches are released, just let it be, but I need to know :)

Hope you can help me.
Thanks in advance!

---

### Edit

Here is the screenshot from `alsamixer` requested in comments. Seems nothing strange to me, but what is that PCM means? Pulse-code modulation?

[image: alsamixer screenshot]

---

### Edit 2

USB headset and Bluetooth speakers are working fine. So, I guess, the problem is in incompability with ALC294. Waiting for updates?

Comment: you may want to run `alsamixer` and observe the slider configurations there. Could provide a clue.

Comment: @richbl updated the question with a screenshot from `alsamixer`

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu 22.04.3 on Vivobook Pro 15 k6500ZE, Win11 dualboot

I was banging my head againts the wall with this too.
An intresting thread from 2020...
https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=206289

"we are in contact with realtek to get to the buttom of this". Seems like no luck for a proper solution. Anyway what "solved" it for me:

uname -a:

`Linux BB-8 5.19.17-051917-generic #202210240939 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Mon Oct 24 09:43:01 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

0. usual dualboot, win11 first.
1. Turn off fast boot from BIOS and from Win11 (power button settings)
2. install alsa-tools
3. update kernel to 5.19.17 (mainline gui app.)
4. I ran these two lines and the second seems to work.

```
sudo hda-verb /dev/snd/hwC0D0 0x20 0x500 0xf
sudo hda-verb /dev/snd/hwC0D0 0x20 0x400 0x7774
```

I don't like these "put it in rice" kind of solutions.
Some ppl got it solved by entering all 4 lines, force shutting down with power button, booting in and out of windows and ubuntu. lol.
As I notice this is a different hex number, none of the "usual" ones that ppl try.

Hope this works for you.
I try to automate this and observe more.

---

Edit 1:
I would add that the combo jack headphone microphone did not work too.

I observed some lower bass with headphones in music too and maaybe it got better after this.

tried this in:
/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf

```
#try for no headset mic:
options snd-hda-intel position fix=1
options snd-hda-intel model=aspire-headset-mic
```

rebooted and headset microphone got recognized through the combo jack.

(aspire? I dunno, it works. :') )

---

Edit 2:

I made a repo for the sound/mic issue, some battery management and I mention the CPU throttling issue here:
https://github.com/dolikemedo/K6500ZE-Linux

---

Edit 3:

Works on 6.2 aswell.
`Linux BB-8 6.2.0-36-generic #37~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Mon Oct  9 15:34:04 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`